# Is there a way to list the most used tags without an excerpt and/or tag wiki?

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

When filling in blank tag wikis it seems most useful to fill in those for the most used tags first, or of course the subset of those about which I know enough (-:

But I can't find a way to get a list of unwikified tags or even better most used tags with no wiki (or excerpt). Is there a way and if not, can we consider this question to be a feature request?

Comment: Sort by popularity - http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular - which happens to be the default - and then browse through the pages until you find an empty one.

Comment: @ChrisF: That sounds like an answer to me...

Comment: @Cody - I assumed the OP was actually after a query rather than a manual method...

Comment: Sounds like a workaround to me (-;

Comment: @hippietrail - *that's* the word I was looking for ;)

Comment: Yes I did already know the manual method. It seems those of us who enjoy helping improve the tag wikis would do more of it if there were some tools to help us.